# Neo4j parameters in match not working as in create

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there something I am not understanding here? My create cypher works fine with parameters while my match cypher doesn't work

```
CREATE (n:user {parameters})
RETURN n
```

This works

```
MATCH (n:user {username: "pewpewlasers"})-[:SOME_REL]->(o {parameters})
RETURN n
```

This does not work

EDIT: As an example case we can assume json params sent to it as

```
{
   parameters:{
       name: "pew pew",
       status: 1
   }
}
```

EDIT 2:

In other words, this works:

```
CREATE (n:user {parameters}) RETURN n
```

This does not:

```
MATCH (n:user {parameters}) RETURN n
```

Instead, you have to do:

```
MATCH (n:user { foo: {foo_param}, bar: {bar_param} }) RETURN n
```

Why?

Comment: When you say "does not work" do you mean it returns nothing?  Are you sure that pattern even exists?   What exactly does "not working" mean here?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Yes it returns null, no errors, no results

Comment: Then there isn't a node in the db with that username.

Comment: Yeah, uh, I'm wondering what other mitigating factors there are here.  The most simple explanation is that that data isn't in your graph.  What other code/evidence do you have to suggest that it should be?

Comment: Don't you need to do `(o: { name: {name_params}, status: {status_param} })`?

Comment: @subvertallchris yes exactly, this is what i realized too but why does simple `{parameters}` work in `CREATE` while in `MATCH` you need to manually enter the values?

Comment: I was unaware that you could do that but just tested, that's a cool surprise. The error I get when trying it with a match says `Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. "{id: {param}.id}")`. It's just the way it works for whatever reason.

Comment: I'd wager a bet that the reason you can use a parameter map (a hash with keys and values) in a CREATE but not a MATCH has to do with the way the execution plan caches queries. It doesn't cache property names in a CREATE but it can and does during a MATCH, so it prevents you from using a parameter map to ensure you give it as much cacheable information as possible.